# message.content.includes doesn't works (?)

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

```
const banWord = ["meat","fruit","road"];
    for (var i = 0; i < banWord.length; i++) {
        if(message.content.includes(banWord[i])) {
            message.channel.send('Mohon yang sopan ya...');
        }
      }
```

the bot won't say anything at discord server when someone says that words.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot remember the exact thing, but here is something off my memory. Instead of `message.content.includes()`, you might be able to use `message.content.has()`. Again, I am not sure, nor I can try right now. So, sorry in advance if it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You need to put that script inside of a client function. For example:

```
client.on('message', message => {
    for (var i = 0; i < banWord.length; i++){
        if(message.content.includes(banWord[i])) {
            message.channel.send('Mohon yang sopan ya...')
        }
    }
})
```